# OS development. How to start?

Tags: c++, c, operating-system, kernel

I am java developer. I always wanted to write my own kernel and develop an small os, I don't know what this kernel or os will look like or what they will do but I have a passion develop something useful to contribute to this vast and beautiful open source world. I want to do this but my problem is that I don't know how to start. I had studied c/c++ in my college days, now I don't remember much of these programming languages but I can brush that up to get started. I know this journey would be difficult and long but each long journey starts with a single step.

To make sure I take correct step in right direction I need help of experts on this forum to guide me to correct direction. I am not expecting spoon feeding but your thoughts on this and references to the good books and links that could help a newbie like me to get started with such programming.

Thanks

Comment: If you start writing your own kernel, it's unlikely that you'll be contributing to the OSS community anytime soon, but it's definitely a greatly edifying experience. Have a look at the [osdev wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Main_Page).

Comment: What about start by reading, or contributing to Linux. I guess you need a huge experience to do it...

Comment: As I am looking to start from scratch so it is obvious to have questions like this so please comment for downrating.

Comment: @Sandy: Open question, showing lack of independant research (i.e., you didn't even search the web for your question title). This bodes ill for your endeavour... (Disclaimer: No downvote from me.)

Comment: @DevSolar: I understand your point and I did searched web for similar question but all links that I found was different in a way that the persons who asked such questions were already had good background or experience of c/c++ and other stuffs or environment  required to get started with OS and Kernel programming.

Comment: @KerrekSB: I am not intended to develop new UNIX or Linux Kernel but a simplest one just for getting started and getting good hands on this so that I should be able to understand OS programming in a better way and do not break anything while I take part in OS projects

Comment: @Sandy: That is because mastery at your language of choice is more or less a *requirement* for OS work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest:

> I don't know what this kernel or os will look like or what they will do but I have a passion develop something useful to contribute to this vast and beautiful open source world.

If your aim is to contribute to the Open Source software pool, *do not* attempt to write an operating system, but pick a different thing to do. There are literally *hundreds* of OS projects, some of them several years in the making, and the general consensus of the OS development community over at [OSDev.org](http://www.osdev.org) is that it is interesting and fun, but not necessarily productive.

If you insist, follow that link I gave; you will find information and further links there.

**Edit:** If you are looking for an interesting project to learn a new language with, pick something that *you* would want to use. There's a reason why so many people have programmed a calculator or an address management in their early days. But seriously, C++ in kernel space is so very much different from C++ in application development that they could just as well be different languages.

Comment: My own OS or Kernel is just for getting started and getting good hands on this so that I should be able to understand OS programming in a better way and do not break anything while I take part in OS projects.

Comment: @Sandy: "Kernel space" is the most hostile programming environment imaginable. You start with no debugger, no exception / runtime support, and no standard library. It will take *several man-years* before your OS will be able to support SATA, hard drives, optical drives, a network connection, file systems, and a console - and I haven't started about a GUI, 3D acceleration, or the plethora of things that should be available in user space.

Comment: @Sandy: And in programming all this, you will learn a lot about these things themselves, and it might make you a better all-around programmer. But **don't work on an OS to learn a new language**. I've been participating in the OSDev community for over a decade, and I tell you: They **all** failed. You have to **be** good, nay *excellent*  at your language of choice *before* you start OS programming to get anywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a good counseling. I think "no pain no gain" so I will definitely keep your words in mind and will at least try things out, whether I succeed or fails that doesn't matter. :)